# How to upload a CSV file with HTTP headers

Tags: csv, header, pykcharts

I'm trying to use the Pictograph of [pykcharts](http://pykcharts.com/)
I'm having a problem in retrieving my csv file.

Here is the error I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http:// my domain here /cust_pictograph.csv. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http:// localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

```js
  <script>
   window.PykChartsInit = function (e) {
   var k = new PykCharts.other.pictograph({

      //Chart Container Id
      "selector": "#my_chart",
    
      //Data file path
      "data": "http://my domain/cust_pictograph.csv",
      

      //Chart Size Parameters
      "chart_width": 100,
      "chart_height": 100,
    
      //Realtime data parameters
      "real_time_charts_last_updated_at_enable": "no",
      "real_time_charts_refresh_frequency": 0,
    
      //Chart-interactive parameters
      "transition_duration": 0,
    
      //Other parameters
      "pictograph_total_count_enable": "no",
      "pictograph_current_count_enable": "no",
      "pictograph_image_per_line": 3,
      "pictograph_image_width": 30,
      "pictograph_image_height": 30,
      "pictograph_total_count_size": 20,
      "pictograph_total_count_weight": "normal",
      "pictograph_total_count_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      "pictograph_total_count_color": "grey",
      "pictograph_current_count_size": 20,
      "pictograph_current_count_weight": "normal",
      "pictograph_current_count_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      "pictograph_current_count_color": "#255AEE",
      "pictograph_units_per_image_text_size": 10,
      "pictograph_units_per_image_text_color": "grey",
      "pictograph_units_per_image_text_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      "pictograph_units_per_image_text_weight": "normal",
    
      //Chart title parameters
      // "title_text": "Enter title here",
      // "title_size": 2,
      // "title_weight": "bold",
      // "title_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      // "title_color": "#1D1D1D",
    
      // //Chart subtitle parameters
      // "subtitle_text": "Enter subtitle here",
      // "subtitle_size": 2,
      // "subtitle_weight": "normal",
      // "subtitle_family": "Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif",
      // "subtitle_color": "black",
    
      //Credits parameters
      "credit_my_site_name": "a",
      "credit_my_site_url": "a"
   });
   k.execute();
  }
   </script>
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This error append because you try to load `http://yourdomain.com` from `http://localhost`.

Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the **same origin policy**.

see more: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

You can, on your `http://yourdomain.com` return a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow some domains:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://from.domain.com
```

or every domains via :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But be careful, this last solution let people load your data from anywhere.

I don't know if you can set to `http://localhost`, but you can try ?

more details: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

### In Aspx file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
Response.Write(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\serverpath\to\file\cust_pictograph.csv"));
Response.End();
```

Comment: How do I make my domain return a header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

Comment: you can add `Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://yourdomain.com");` in your aspx page. more info on http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: i still get "Origin http://localhost not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header"

Comment: Can you try with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to be sure that localhost is not the problem ?

Comment: It's still not working :( I just want to get the CSV file

Comment: can you give me a test page url that i can try to access on this server ? Can you update your question and add your javascript code ?

Comment: `http://my domain/cust_pictograph.csv` is a csv file on the server or an aspx file that return the csv contents ?

Comment: it's a csv file on the server.

Comment: Can you create a `http://my domain/cust_pictograph.aspx` file with the code i suggest in my updated answer and call this url to retrieve the CSV ? (replace the path with your csv server path)